# How to return json data to javascript in a springboot controller?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf, bootstrap-table

How to return json data to javascript so the bootstrap-table can use it?(I want to initialize it in javascript)

I am using springboot as my backend, bootstrap to design my html page and bootstrap table to show my data. This bootstrap-table should be initialized with json data from controller when this html page completely loaded.

What blocks me is that I don't know how to return json data to javascript so the bootstrap-table can use it.

In a controller, if I return a template as a string I can not return my json data and if I return json data and add an @ResponseBody I just get a page with json string, I can not reach my template let alone to use json data to initialize bootstrap table.

some code from controller:

```
ArrayList<AISResponse> aisResponses = new ArrayList<AISResponse>();
AISResponse aisResponse = new AISResponse();
aisResponse.setAISPath(AISPath);
aisResponse.setTmID(tmID);
aisResponse.setTmName(tmName);
aisResponses.add(aisResponse);
model.addAttribute("aisResponses", aisResponses);
return "AIS/UI_AIS_Properties"
```

some code from html page:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true"
        data-search="true" data-page-size="30">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sortable="true">AISPath</th>
                <th data-sortable="true">TM Name</th>
                <th data-sortable="true">TM ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="r:${aisResponses}">
                <td th:text="${r.AISPath}"></td>
                <td th:text="${r.tmID}"></td>
                <td th:text="${r.tmName}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

For now I am using Thymeleaf to iterate aisResponses, so I can show my data in table.
But I want to initialize table in javascript by directly return json data to javascript, I think that will make my html page more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ModelAndView` or `Model` in this case. Both are used to define a model in a Spring MVC application. Model defines a holder for model attributes and is primarily designed for adding attributes to the model. And your code should look like below.

```
@RestController
public class YourController{

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getAisList(){

    ModelAndView   modelView = new ModelAndView ("AIS/UI_AIS_Properties");

    ArrayList<AISResponse> aisResponses = new ArrayList<AISResponse>();
    AISResponse aisResponse = new AISResponse();
    aisResponse.setAISPath(AISPath);
    aisResponse.setTmID(tmID);
    aisResponse.setTmName(tmName);
    aisResponses.add(aisResponse);

    modelView.addObject("aisResponses", aisResponses);
    return modelView;

        }             
    }
```